# Is pas and non plus separated in dual verb constructions?

Tags: verbes, négation, adverbes, ordre-des-mots

I want to say "I can't work here either" in French. Should I say

"*Je ne peux pas non plus travailler ici*"

or

"*Je ne peux pas travailler ici non plus*"

What are the rules governing the placement of this and other similar negatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your suggestions are acceptable and used although their meaning might be slightly different depending on the context.

> *Je ne peux pas non plus travailler ici.*

"I can't work here like I can't do something else I just talk about" (e.g.: *Il y a trop de bruit, je n'arrive pas à dormir. Je ne peux pas non plus travailler ici*) or "Like you/someone else, I can't work here."

> *Je ne peux pas travailler ici non plus.*

For some reason, I can't work here just like I can't work elsewhere. (e.g.: *Je n'ai pas le permis requis, Je ne peux pas travailler ici non plus.*) or "Like you/someone else, I can't work here" (same as above.)

I'd probably say it another way to make clear what I mean:

> Ici non plus, je (ne) peux pas travailler.

or

> Moi non plus, je (ne) peux pas travailler ici.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you help me translate "I am not going to scare or hurt anyone" into French? I am a little confused with the use of ne...ni...ni.

Comment: That's a different question so better to ask it as a new one with your attempts.